# Correctly passing a vector by reference or pointer

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I try to (basically) make a Setter method for a std::vector (its D3D10 rendering)

```
void GraphicsClass::BeginFrame(vector<LightClass> const &vlights)
{
    lights = vlights;
```

where lights is a private member of GraphicsClass, declaration:

```
vector<LightClass> lights;
```

Now, the properties of the array get copied; but the elements `lights[0], lights[1]` etc contain garbage. I checked this using the Visual Studio debugger.

I could obviously work around by using

```
void GraphicsClass::BeginFrame(vector<LightClass> const &vlights) {
    int size = vlights.size();
    int i;
    lights.resize(size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
       lights[i] = vlights[i];
```

But I don't like that I don't understand this topic, and this code seems a good bit slower.

Thanks in advance for answers!

LightClass as requested:

```
class LightClass
{
public:
LightClass(void);
~LightClass(void);
void SetDiffuseColor(float, float, float, float);
void SetDirection(float, float, float);

D3DXVECTOR4 GetDiffuseColor();
D3DXVECTOR3 GetDirection();

 private:
D3DXVECTOR4 m_diffuseColor;
D3DXVECTOR3 m_direction;
};
```

both the constructor and the destructor are empty which is a mistake (I copied this from classes which I only create pointers to. like Type *thing. I'm new to OOP)

I will probably change the vector to vector though.

Comment: Also, the VS debugger may not show you correct information, especially if you're debugging an optimized build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have implemented a copy constructor for `LightClass`, not just `operator=` (as in your workaround).

Comment: What does that mean exactly?
I understand a copy constructor is
void LightClass(const LightClass&)
{ something} 
what do I have to do there? And why is that necessary?

Comment: You say that you're getting garbage after copying the whole array.  This is because both copy and assign on a `vector` invokes the copy constructor on the contained elements. If your copy constructor is empty, the elements will contain garbage until initialized. Compilers don't automatically know how to copy class members, even if it might seem straightforward.

Comment: To clarify, as long as you *don't* declare a copy constructor, you'll get a default member-wise copy, but that may or may not work depending on the member types and your intentions. You're better off defining one explicitly.

Comment: Ok, so I have to implement a copy constructor filled with code that makes sense. Thanks for the help!